# The number of vertices that the traversing algorithm visited with at least d sons

Tags: combinatorics

Given a directed tree $T$ with $n$ leaves, each vertex has at least $2$ sons.  Let's define $d(v)$ as the number of outgoing edges of vertex $v$ or the number of its sons.

A traversing algorithm is defined as follows:
Starting from the tree root and for each step, the next vertex is chosen uniformly from the current vertex's sons, with probability $\frac{1}{d(v)}$.

Let $Z_d$ be the number of vertices that the algorithm visited with at least $d$ sons.

We would like to prove that:
$$E(Z_d) \leq \frac{\log(n)}{\log(d)}$$

I notice that $n + 1 \leq |v| \leq 2n + 1$. The single root case is the lower bound, and if the tree is a chain with leaves is the upper bound.

Therefore, if we define $K$ as the number of vertices with at least $d$ sons we can say that
$$K \cdot d \leq |V| - 1 \leq 2n + 1 - 1 = 2n$$
$$K \leq \frac{2n}{d}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, I suggest changing your title to something along the lines of proving that the number of vertices that the traversing algorithm visited with at least $d$ sons is at most $\frac{\log(n)}{\log(d)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the advise

Answer (score 2):

Let the root have $s$ sons and proceed by induction on the height of the tree.

BASE CASE

Suppose the tree has height $1$. If $s<d$ then $E_d=0$ and there is nothing to prove. If $s\ge d$ then $n=s$ and $E_d=1 \le \frac{\log n}{\log d}. $

THE INDUCTIVE STEP

Suppose  $s\ge d$ sons and let the $i$th son be the root for a tree with $n_i$ leaves. If the $i$th son is chosen initially, then the expected number of vertices visited which have at least $d$ sons is less than or equal to $1+\frac{\log(n_i)}{\log(d)}$.

By the AM-GM inequality, $$\log{(n_1n_2...n_s)}^{1/s}\le \log \big (\frac{{n}}{s}\big ). $$

The sons are each chosen with probability $\frac{1}{s}$ and so the required expected value is at most $$ 1+ \frac{1}{s}\sum  \frac{\log{n_i}}{\log d}=\frac{\log d+\log{(n_1n_2...n_s)^{1/s}}}{\log d} \le \frac{\log \big (\frac{{nd}}{s}\big )}{\log d} \le \frac{\log n}{\log d}. $$

If $d<s$ then the above sum is reduced and so the inequality is still true.

Comment: thank you it was very helpful

Comment: Glad to have helped.